# Looking for a script or program to convert all HTTP links to HTTPS

Tags: html, http, https

I am trying to find a script or program to convert my html website links from http to https.

I have looked all over hundreds of search results and web articles and I used the Word Press SSL plugin but it missed numerous pages with http links.

Below is one of thousands of my links I need to convert:
http://www.robert-b-ritter-jr.com/2015/11/30/blog-121-we-dont-need-the-required-minimum-distributions-rmds

I am looking for a way to do this quickly instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTPS Everywhere extension](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) will automatically rewrite unsecure HTTP requests to HTTPS. Keep in mind not all websites offer a secure and encrypted connection.